# how do i preserve text in input when closing popopver with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have currently implemented a popover on my page with Bootstrap 2.  The popover has a text input in the html.  I want the text in the input to be preserved when showing/hiding the popover.  How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
var temptext;
$('#myPopover').on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
  temptext = $("#input").val();
})
```

Does it work? If not,:

```
$( "#input" ).change(function() {
    temptext = $("#input").val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above by Daniel Cheung does not work in the event that you need to maintain event bindings to elements that are inside the popover.  The solution that worked for me was to simply identify that the parent container for any popover had a class of 'popover', which meant that we could apply our own Jquery logic hide/show the popover contents.

$('.popover').hide() //hides popover
$('.popover').show() //shows popover

If you want to get fancy, you should be able to adjust the id of each popover as you initialize them before binding events if you want to have multiple popovers working at the same time; I just didn't have this need.